# WordPress Shortcode In HTML Doc

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, shortcode

I want to use a WordPress shortcode (for a videoplayer) in an adspace in HTML.

Do I php echo in a div that calls from a html doc or should I attempt any other step?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Most commonly used like this `<?php echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]'); ?>`

Comment: If you are inserting a shortcode directly into source code use `echo do_shortcode('[the_shortcode]');`, else for for backend text editors just insert the shortcode directly, e.g: `[the_shortcode]`

Comment: The ad space is for javascript/html.

Shortcodes only result in the shortcode text displaying.

So how do I load a shortcode here?